# How to set dropdown value to zero?

Tags: php, ajax

I have the three dropdown lists which are dependent on each other:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('island_id',$island,$locationsList, 
                            array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getRegions'),
                                                'update'=>'#region_id',),
                                  'id'=>'island_id',
                                  'empty'=>'Choose Island',
                            )); 
    echo " ";
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('region_id',$region, $regionsList, 
                            array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getProvinces'),
                                                'update'=>'#province_id',),
                                  'id'=>'region_id',
                                  'empty'=>'Choose Region',
                            ));
    echo " ";
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('province_id',$province,$provincesList, array('empty'=>'Choose Province'));
```

The first dropdown does an update to '#region_id' but I also want it to change #province_id to be set to empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing you can show province dropdown null until the region is selected and on selection of region you can update the province.

Comment: It's always null until the region is updated.

The problem is let's say that the user changes their mind about the island (parent). The province value does not go to null or update. If there's a way to make the 3rd dropdown list null when the parent is set, that would solve all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('island_id',$island,$locationsList, 
                        array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('supplierHead/getRegions'),
                                            'update'=>'#region_id',),
                              'id'=>'island_id',
                              'empty'=>'Choose Island',
                              'onchange'=>'$("#province_id").html("<option value=''>Choose Province</option>")'
                        ));
```

Please check qoutes for onchange value,

Comment: This answer didn't do what I was hoping it would do. It did not make the province drop down null :(